# How to publish a react native app to test flight from in windows 10

Tags: react-native, testflight

I need to publish my react native application to test flight from windows environment

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it on Windows 10.
You need XCode to archive the app and send it to ITunes, where you can use tesflight

Actually, you can't even run the iOS app on Device without XCode.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#docsNav

Comment: Thanks buddy I think I need to set up a virtual machine with MAC OS